# How to remove certain lines from last commit and add them to a new commit in git?

Tags: git

In my last commit I added a certain lines in a file, which should've been added as a separate commit. How do I undo only those lines from the commit without deleting them altogether (as I still need to add them later)?

I know I can do `git reset HEAD~1` to undo the commit entirely and then patch add `git add -p` only the lines I need and then commit it again. I was actually looking for a cleaner solution (if one exists)

Answer (score 3):

This is the fastest I can think of.

- undo those lines, then `git add .`
- `git commit --amend --no-edit` (assuming you won't change your last git commit message)
- then add the lines you need for new commit.

Comment: How exactly do you suggest undoing the commit? I know of two ways `git reset --hard HEAD~1` and `git checkout HEAD~1`, but using `amend` after either would actually amend the commit currently at `HEAD~1` (the parent of the commit from which I want to remove the lines).

Comment: Those steps actually edits the last commit to delete/add lines you do/don't need. This `git reset --hard HEAD~1` is entirely deleting the last commit, so it entails more work.

Answer (score 1):

Some changes to `@~` shouldn't be in `@` but in another branch, so reset them here:

```
git reset -p @~ -- that/file
git commit
```

commit them there

```
git checkout another
git commit -p -- that/file
```

```
git checkout @{-1}    # aannd we're back
```

There's special-case logic in `git commit -- path` that says "I don't care what the index looks like, commit only the changes to the specific paths I gave you and ignore everything else".  It's built specifically for cases like this, where you fixed something that needs recording separately.  Just fix what's in front of you in your worktree, then drop-ship the changes wherever and however you want them recorded.

This, by the way, is also a handy shortcut for rebase, to completely refactor your current branch you can

```
git reset --soft `git merge-base @{u} @`
```

and then do patch commits for your changes, switching and/or making branches as desired.  Once you get comfy with *that* worfklow, there's even `git checkout --merge`, which runs an impromptu content merge with your current tip as the base, it can be noticeably easier to resolve minor conflicts than to do the stash-and-pop dance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's really anything cleaner than that. Depending on how much you're looking at pulling out and how its dispersed, `git commit --amend` would be maybe simpler if you just want to pull out a few separate lines or a large consecutive chunk and re-add + commit them as a part of the next commit.

Comment: How do we remove lines with `git commit --amend`?

Comment: well, you remove the lines manually from the files. Then you do `git add .` to stage the files without those lines and `git commit --amend`. You are not actually *undoing* the wrong commit. You're overwriting it. Like it will be replaced in your log as though you had never committed extra lines. This is more effective if removing lines manually is doable. @meshde

Answer (score 0):

1. `git add` -> this will add all files that have been modified
2. `git commit --amend --no-edit` -> this will merge all changes that were added or removed to your previous commit, without changing the message

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please [edit] this answer to add details how this answer a) answers the question and b) is different than the highest voted question -- others may downvote your for those reasons :)